# Django. Как в ModelAdmin в поле prepopulated_fields передать pk

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-admin

Использую для генерации url поле SlugField в модели в связке с prepopulated_fields в админке, и для того чтобы поле slug было уникально решил передать параметр id в prepopulated_fields. Но Django выдает мне ошибку и говори что это поле нельзя использовать в prepopulated_fields. Как можно slug сделать уникальным(применение id в конце не обязательно), при том что поле с которого оно генерируется не уникально?

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title","id")}
```

Comment: Один из элементов, по которым генерируется slug, должен быть уникальным, либо же создать ещё одно поле, где будут генерироваться рандомные уникальные символы. Но это не очень красиво будет. Лучше всего здесь делать по связке - title-id.

Comment: Пробовал еще в методе save сделать конкатенацию slug с id, но поле id при первой записи еще не определено.

Comment: @m0nte-cr1st0 , и как получить или создать его? Второй AutoField нельзя сделать в одной модели, а pk по умолчанию или поле id, что я указал, создается уже первого сохранения.

Comment: смотрите ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Генерация slug по id

## Вариант 1

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank = True, null=True)

    def save(self):
        super(Product, self).save()
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title) + '-' + str(self.id)
            super(Product, self).save()
```

В таком случае вам не нужно использовать `prepopulated_fields`

## Вариант 2

**admin.py**

```
@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("title",)}
```

**models.py**

```
def save(self):
    super(Product, self).save()
    if not self.slug.endswith('-' + str(self.id)):
        self.slug += '-' + str(self.id)
        super(Product, self).save()
```

Comment: все работает, но как запретить добавление id при изменении записи через админку?

Comment: подправил код..

Comment: Спасибо, код работает. Но я бы хотел бы использовать prepopulated_fields, думаю есть возможность проверить когда вызывается метод save, при создании или при изменении. Так было бы корректнее, не знаете случаем как это сделать? А сейчас просто проверяю наличие id в slug, но это как по мне костыль.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то смотрите Вариант 2.